# how to add bookmark and hyperlink to a table cell in python

Tags: python, xml, hyperlink, docx, bookmarks

I am trying to add bookmark to a cell in an existing table and want to create the hyperlink in a separate page.

I have seen a tutorial on how to create a bookmark and hyperlink but only to a run here:
[how to create bookmarks in a word document, then create internal hyperlinks to the bookmark w/ python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586400/how-to-create-bookmarks-in-a-word-document-then-create-internal-hyperlinks-to-t)

Below is my code, when run it successfully created the file. But when I open the file cannot be opened as it gives out an error.

Not sure though if my code is correct. I grabbed them from all over the internet trying which one would work. Appreciate if anyone can point to the right direction. Just started learning python and programming in general

```
from docx import Document
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.oxml.shared import OxmlElement


document = Document("sample rows.docx")
table = document.tables[0]
rows = table.rows
xml_cell = rows[1].cells[0]._tc

start = OxmlElement('w:bookmarkStart')
start.set(qn('w:id'), 'row1')
start.set(qn('w:name'), 'row1')
start.set(qn('w:colFirst'), '0')
start.set(qn('w:colLast'), '0')
xml_cell.append(start)

end = OxmlElement('w:bookmarkEnd')
end.set(qn('w:id'), 'row1')
end.set(qn('w:name'), 'row1')
xml_cell.append(end)


# Adding new page and table
document.add_page_break()
new_table = document.add_table(1, 1)
cell = new_table.add_row().cells[0]
cell.text = "This is row 1 link"
c_tc = cell._tc

hyperlink = OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
hyperlink.set(qn('w:anchor'), 'row1')

c_tc.append(hyperlink)


document.save("sample rows1.docx")
```

Update: I reverted to using run in my bookmark by extracting it form inside the cell as I was not able to find solution to adding bookmark to a cell. I will still put out the question above in the hopes that somebody will answer. The below code works for me (not related to the above code).

```
 def add_bookmark(self, run, title_id):
    run_tag = run._r
    # create start bookmark
    start = OxmlElement('w:bookmarkStart')
    start.set(qn('w:id'), f'{title_id}')
    start.set(qn('w:name'), f'{title_id}')
    run_tag.append(start)

    text = OxmlElement('w:r')
    text.text = ''
    run_tag.append(text)
    # create end bookmark
    end = OxmlElement('w:bookmarkEnd')
    end.set(qn('w:id'), f'{title_id}')

    run_tag.append(end)

def add_hyperlink(self, title_id, paragraph):
    hyperlink = OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(qn('w:anchor'), f'{title_id}')

    new_run = OxmlElement('w:r')
    rPr = OxmlElement('w:rPr')
    new_run.append(rPr)
    new_run.text = f"<Title>"
    hyperlink.append(new_run)
    r = paragraph.add_run()
    r._r.append(hyperlink)
    r.font.name = "Calibri"
    r.font.italic = True
    r.font.color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR_INDEX.HYPERLINK
    r.font.underline = True
```

Answer (score 0):

See the document https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/docx/table.html?highlight=._element.
If you want to create a link to ,say, the cell(0,0) of table.You can create a link to  table.cell(0,0).paragraphs[0].Actually the content of a cell is also a block-level object(https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html),which must contain at least one paragraph.