# Is it possible to add hyperlinks to bookmarks with python docx that work when converted to pdf

Tags: python, xml, docx, python-docx

I am trying to create a report, first in word, then later as a pdf, that has summary data on the first page and then create links to the detail later in the document.  My plan is to create bookmarks and hyperlinks as I construct the report. I am using python-docx package to create the document.

I have tried this solution [Adding an hyperlink in MSWord by using python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666642/adding-an-hyperlink-in-msword-by-using-python-docx) which is clickable when saved as pdf but creates an external link. With this solution I tried changing part.relate_to() "is_external" to False but it through a Value error.

And I have tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786239/18650243 which creates the bookmark and link but it does not work when I save as pdf.

I tried adding the Hyperlink Style function (def get_or_create_hyperlink_style(d):) from the first solution to the second solution which worked and made the xml more similar but not exact and it still didn't save to pdf.

I compared the difference in the xml of the links these produce and it appears that the link that does not save to pdf is missing this info <w:p w14:paraId="2318C920" w14:textId="19560908" w:rsidR="001E33CA" w:rsidRDefault="001E33CA">. I am new to xml/parsing xml so any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I think this resolves to two separate questions. The first one to tackle would be: "Can I convert .docx to .pdf retaining internal links (to bookmarks)". I recommend you make a docx file by hand, using Word, that has the kind of links you want, and then look for a converter that does preserves those into PDF. If you're able to achieve that, then the second challenge is how to make one of these internal links in a docx using Python, which I believe is a solved problem or at least tractable.

Comment: Hi scanny, The issue is that the available methods for creating the internal links, create xml such that when I save to pdf manually, they look like hyperlinks but are not clickable. If I create the internal link using the word interface and save to pdf, the links work.

Comment: I see. That narrows it down. Do you create both the bookmark and the link to the bookmark? Also, an internal hyperlink doesn't use a URL, only the so-called "anchor" (`w:anchor` I believe) attribute of the `w:hyperlink` element. Can you expand your question to show what you've done that isn't working (as concisely as possible of course :)

Comment: Its working now. I'm so fried from grinding on this. The anchor id I was using wasn't correct. I'm not convinced that's all that it was as I've made various changes to the code for the last day and a half. I will report back if I have any insights.