# Adding a link to a bookmark in MS Word using python docx library

Tags: python, hyperlink, bookmarks, python-docx

I've used the code from an earlier question to create a hyperlink: 
[Adding an hyperlink in MSWord by using python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666642/adding-an-hyperlink-in-msword-by-using-python-docx/47666747)

I now want to create a link to a bookmark within the document, rather than an external hyperlink, but can't work out how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: This solution may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586400/how-to-create-bookmarks-in-a-word-document-then-create-internal-hyperlinks-to-t Best

Answer (score 2):

Found a way, thanks to neilbilly at github:
[feature: Paragraph.add_hyperlink() #74](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/74)

```py
def add_link(paragraph, link_to, text):
    hyperlink = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:anchor'), link_to, )
    new_run = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:r')
    rPr = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:rPr')
    new_run.append(rPr)
    new_run.text = text
    hyperlink.append(new_run)
    r = paragraph.add_run ()
    r._r.append (hyperlink)
    r.font.name = "Calibri"
    r.font.color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR_INDEX.HYPERLINK
    r.font.underline = True
```